# Cocoa: Entry point after view presented on the screen?

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'd like to start an operation as soon as the complete GUI of my OS X application has been presented on the screen.

My ViewController's "viewDidLoad()" is not being called in my case and "awakeFromNib()" seems to be called too early (my operations will be executed but no GUI is visible).

Reason for me to do that: I want to start some searching operations on application launch (without bothering the user to press a button)."awakeFromNib()" prevents the GUI from being shown which is very bad because the user does not know what's going on (searches may take a while).

Does anybody have a clue where I have to put my code in order to start it immediately AND let the GUI reflect the current operations?

I'm using Swift with Xcode Beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is to start your long running operation on a background queue using either GCD or NSOperationQueues, This won't block your main UI thread. You then either have a delegate call-back or a block that runs when your operation is completed which lets you update your UI appropriately.

Comment: Usually I would do yo, you're right. But the operations I need to perform (NSMetadataQueries for Spotlight searches) need to be called from the main thread (as apple documentation mentions). I already tried to run them in a separate queue. They have been started but I did never receive any "finished" notification. So I have to find another way.

Comment: To add something: I tried to wrap the calls in a "dispatch_async()" call (just another place within my app). And I receive the notifications now. As these calls have been placed on the main thread the GUI is still blocking. Tried the DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT queue. But this doesn't seem to work at all.